# Prove that $\sum (-1)^n \sin(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$ converges by Leibniz

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\sin\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right)$ converges by Leibniz.

The answer says that $\sin$ is continuous, monotonic around $0$ and the limit there is $0$, therefore the series conditionally converges by the Leibniz test.

I don't understand, Leibniz says that we need an $a_n$ which is monotonic decreasing to $0$, How they took this sentence and say that just around $0$ it is ok and enough for the proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is you're looking at the magnitude $\sin\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Take a look at what happens to $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ - it monotonically decreases to $0$. That means for large enough $n$, the argument to $\sin$ is close to $0$.

At this point, since $\sin$ is itself monotonic around $0$, applying a monotonic function to a monotonic sequence leaves it monotonic.

Comment: So its ok to say, from some point the $a_n$ is decreasing to $0$ and not $\forall n$ but almost $\forall n$?

Comment: For(all) *sufficiently large* $n$ is what you want. If you need to be precise, that's "given $\epsilon>0$, then $\forall n>N$" (for some $N$ that the existence of a limit gives you).

Answer (score 0):

If you consider $\sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}})$, then as $n \to \infty, \sin$ can be comapred to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$, and then the series you have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k b_k
$$ 
The first term $a_k = (-1)^k \to |\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k|<1=M$, the second term is monotone, and so the series converges by Dirichlet test, so the original series converges too.